# Unittest Webapp2 auth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-unittest, webapp2

I want to write a unittest for a `GAE application` where authentication is managed via `webapp2_extras`.

How to mock authenticated user for access to `HTTP verbs` decorated by `'user_required'` ,which check if user is authenticated.

Thanks

Comment: Check if [Simulating login](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Simulating_login) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use a testing tool such as [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) that controls a web browser and conduct your tests that way.